# Missing } Inserted?

Tags: math-mode, align

I wrote

```
    \begin{align}
    $\lim_{x \to 2} f(x)$ &= $\lim_{x \to 2}\dfrac{2x^2-5x+2}{5x^2-7x-6}$\\
                          &= $\lim_{x \to 2}\dfrac{(x-2)(2x-1)}{(x-2)(5x+3)}$\\
    \end{align}
```

But apparently I have a missing } and I cannot find it. Help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Remove the `$` characters: you're already in math mode when you start `align`.

Comment: Oh, so  I don't need the $ characters for the align environment?

Comment: No, they are for inline math formulas, not for displays.

Answer (score 7):

When you start a display environment, be it

```
\begin{equation}

\begin{equation*}

\begin{align}

\begin{align*}

\begin{gather}

\begin{gather*}
```

and the other display environments, you are already in math mode, so a `$` character is illegal.

Type `$<formula>$` only for inline math formulas.

So

```
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 2} f(x) &= \lim_{x \to 2}\dfrac{2x^2-5x+2}{5x^2-7x-6} \\
                    &= \lim_{x \to 2}\dfrac{(x-2)(2x-1)}{(x-2)(5x+3)}
\end{align}
```

Don't add `\\` to the last row of a display environment. It's optional in `array`, but at the outer level in a display environment it would produce an unwanted blank line.